# how to redirect page in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am writing page in html and i have server/database on parse.com . 
parse provides login function which checks if username and password is matched in a database. i have done this part but when i get success it is not redirecting into other page. here is the code :

```
$("#login").click(function(event)
    var name = $(#name).val();
    var pass = $(#password).val();

    Parse.User.logIn(name, pass, { 
        debugger
        success: function(user){
        window.location="login/login.html";

         console.log("everything OK")

     }, error: function(user, error){

           console.log("Log in Error:"+error.message);
     }

   });
});
```

i have searched for redirecting the page and found out the `window.location` but it is not working. what is the error please help me.
By the way i got error message at this line  `var name = $(#name).val();` with error message :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: Shouldn't you wrap your selector in single or double quotes, i.e. `$('#name').val()` or `$("#name").val()`?

Comment: Try `window.location.href="login/login.html"` instead.

Comment: `debuger` is also a syntax error (it takes two `g`s).

Comment: @Terry ... yes, you should ;)

Comment: This is redirecting a page in JS not HTML btw

Comment: i tried single and double quotes but i have got the same error

Comment: Have just edited your code block... take a look and see if you can spot the issue :) ... HINT: `debugger` is just floating about inside that object!

Comment: guys i have changed it and worked but got another message "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"  after success: function(user){ "here"              i don't know what to do :((

Comment: You should take a look at [JavaScript basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics). And forget jQuery (a JavaScript library) until you understand at least the basics of the language itself. You are full of syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems in your code which is stopping it from running. `Unexpected token ILLEGAL` is the browser's way of telling you that it doesn't understand your code.

1) You're missing the opening brace in the first function

2) In the jQuery selectors, you need to wrap the selectors in quotes - `$("#name").val()` and `$("#password").val()`

3) Your `debuger` statement is misplaced. You've put it inside an object definition, and it doesn't make sense there. Move it to inside the function below. (It's also spelt `debugger` with 2 g's :) )

```
$("#login").click(function(event) { // 1) include brace
  var name = $("#name").val(); // 2) include quotes
  var pass = $("#password").val();

  Parse.User.logIn(name, pass, {
    success: function(user){
      debugger; // 3) move debugger statement to a valid location

      window.location="login/login.html";

      console.log("everything OK")

    },
    error: function(user, error) {
      console.log("Log in Error:"+error.message);
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass *both* of your selectors in quotes

```
var name = $("#name").val();
var pass = $("#password").val();
```

That will stop the error and should work.

This is riddled with errors and missing semicolons and parantheses. Try this

```
$("#login").click(function(event) {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var pass = $("#password").val();

    Parse.User.logIn(name, pass, debuger);
    success: function(user){
    window.location="login/login.html";

    console.log("everything OK")

        }, error: function(user, error){

            console.log("Log in Error:"+error.message);
        }

    });

});
```